# page not loading my js files

Tags: validation

I have created a new javascript file to validate my customers emails while they are registering. I followed this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/), however my js file is not loading.

my js is in public_html/js/newValidate.js with content:

```
Validation.add('validate-email', 'Please enter a valid Gmail address. For example johndoe@gmail.com.', function(v) {
return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@gmail\.com)$/i.test(v)
})
```

and I am including the js file editing the  public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">

        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

            <!-- CUSTOM JS BELOW THIS POINT -->
            <action method="addJs"><script>newValidate.js</script></action>
            <!-- CUSTOM JS ABOVE THIS POINT -->
```

However I can't find the js file in the page why is that?

Comment: Do you have any custom theme installed? Did you check your page.xml not calling from somewhere else?

Comment: @AkhileshPatel yes I have a custom theme installed

Comment: if your custom theme layout folder has page.xml. you will need to call js in that file.

Comment: @AkhileshPatel the only page.xml files are app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/page.xml, /app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/page.xml, /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml and /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml

Comment: This is not a proper solution but it solution jut try this code in your theme head.phtml  <script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);?>frontend/package/theme/js/js_filename.js"></script>

Comment: @LearningMagento thanks, will my changes be overwritten if I upgrade my theme?